# Лучший способ реализовать бесконечный цикл в отдельном потоке для Android

Tags: android, android-studio, многопоточность

Есть приложение для Android, создающее и редактирующее заявки. Все данные оно пишет в БД SQLite. Задача: в фоновом режиме проверять БД на наличие определенных записей. Видимо, это будет бесконечный цикл. Интервал между select'ами - 30 секунд. Какой наилучший способ реализовать эту задачу в отдельном потоке? Напишите, пожалуйста, коротенький код реализации.

P.S.: в будущем приложение будет не в БД лезть, а запрашивать данные у сервера. Но все также, в бесконечном цикле и с определенным интервалом между запросами. В отдельном потоке.

Comment: Может не правильно понял вопрос, но зачем бесконечный цикл? Вы же данные вносите в бд, можно просто при добавлении новых записей в бд в отдельном потоке отправить их сразу на сервер.

Comment: Объясню - на данный момент работа происходит только с локальной БД на телефоне, а серверной части пока нет. В будущем, в этом бесконечном цикле предполагается опрос сервера на предмет заявок.

Comment: Если пользователь сам будет вносить правки, тогда вам нужно будет просто сделать прослойку между UI и БД, и хукать изменения и обновлять UI. А если серверную запилите, юзайте сокеты. P.S бесконечные циклы в большинстве случаев говорят о не очень хорошем дизайне архитектуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам следует посмотреть в сторону [Servic-ов](http://Always%20code%20as%20if%20the%20guy%20who%20ends%20up%20maintaining%20your%20code%20will%20be%20a%20violent%20psychopath%20who%20knows%20where%20you%20live.), и добавить [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) например для запуска в определенное время

Comment: Вы правы, это лучше цикла. Использую timer.schedule(...). А вот с тем, что лучше именно для моей задачи - Service, Thread или AsyncTask, пока не определился. А вы считаете, что Service больше подходит? Можете сказать почему?

Comment: Все зависит от Ваших нужд, если обновлять информацию нужно во время работы приложения, то AsyncTask, а если нужно проверять данные даже когда приложение закрыто тогда Service.

Comment: @Vitalii При закрытом приложении - не надо, а вот если оно просто теряет фокус, но все еще в памяти - то нужно. Почему не Thread? Какие преимущества в данном случае имеет AsyncTask?

Comment: Вы можете использовать Thread, просто в AsyncTask уже есть готовые решения, а Thread нужно будет писать свой велосипед. Также можете почитать [1](https://habrahabr.ru/post/124484/), [2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/136942/)

Comment: @Vitalii , спасибо. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264383/difference-between-service-async-task-thread), правда, пишут про AsyncTask так:
"AsyncTask is for a short Task because is tied to the host activity for example if you create a AsyncTask which is going to pull data from a server (DON'T DO THIS) when you rotate the phone and the activity is recreated again the AsyncTask will be recreated." Т.е. это скорее Service нужен, чтобы "pull data from a server"?

Comment: Если нужно получать информацию с сервера, то советую почитать про [Retrofit](https://habrahabr.ru/post/314028/), очень простая и удобная штука. Там eсть возможность получать инфу асинхронно. И да, Вы. правы, для такого нужен сервис.